# P4 - change workspace for client

Tags: perforce

I want to change the workspace client using the p4 command line but i don't know if its possible.
You can create, delete or edit workspace using the p4 workspace command, but i want to change the current workspace with a .bat method.

Exemple : 
p4 -c MyClient changeworkspace myNewWorkspace

If you know in first step if it's possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Either set the P4CLIENT environment variable to the name of the workspace you want to be your current workspace, or consistently pass that workspace name as the value of the -c flag on your p4 commands: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/env.P4CLIENT.html#1040647

See also these other ways to set the environment variable (many people find P4CONFIG files helpful): http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/02_config.html#1069873

Comment: Thanks i was continued findind for issues and i try the P4CONFIG ! So i have found using the p4v command line for launch workspace and don't change the set preferences i use : p4v -p 127.0.0.1:1566 -u Username -c myNewWorkspace in a .bat who launch perforce with my new specification ! it's work :)