# p4 status "Path is not under client's root"

Tags: perforce

I have two Perforce workspaces on my computer, one at `c:\dev` and second at `c:\code` . When I run `p4 status`  in `c:\code` I get an error message

```
Path 'c:\code\...' is not under client's root 'c:\dev'
```

The same happens for `p4 reconcile`. How can I get the commands to work? It's obvious it's trying to run the command against the wrong repo.

Comment: This should be helpful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633332/p4-change-workspace-for-client

Answer (score 18):

If you don't explicitly set the `P4CLIENT` environment variable, Perforce uses the default workspace.  How it decides which workspace is the default, I do not know.  Anyway, it has defaulted to the one whose root you have mapped to `C:\dev`.  You need to switch to workspace `code` (or whatever its actual name is).  At the command line type the following command to switch workspaces:

`p4 set P4CLIENT=[client name]`

Of course, you'll replace "[client name]" with the name of the workspace whose root you have mapped to `C:\code`.

Comment: Did this still getting the same error after setting the client.  Path '/home/stevek/...' is not under client's root '/home/stevek/Perforce/steve_SIA_development'.
No file(s) to reconcile.  Set mine in bash_profile.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding a bit on raven's answer. By default, if you don't set P4CLIENT, perforce takes your machine name as the default client name. So if you want to use another client, you have to use the `p4 set P4CLIENT=[client name]`, which will set it for every instance of p4 you run, no matter which command window you are in. You can can also do a `set P4CLIENT=[client name]` on the command line, which will only be valid in the command window that you are running in.

In addition, you can use `p4 -c [client_name] <command>` since -c is a global option, you can supply it to all p4 commands.

Comment: we can set P4CLIENT in our bash_profile correct?  I am setting my client there but still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that these errors appear when I have filters active in my sub-windows like "Pending", "Workspaces" and so on. Clear the filters and try switching the workspaces afterwards. This might help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your are sending commands on a valid directory (under workspace...)

For example, if your workspace is located in C:\workspace

and you are sending commands from C:\temp

you should use "cd C:\workspace" before "p4 status"

Comment: Thank you!  Since I was following a symlink to my directory, Linux didn't understand my client path and symlinked path were the same location.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using P4V open the "Pending" tab and clear all filters (the red X button). Toggle open the filter menu in the same tab, then set your "Workspace" filter to "Current Workspace" in the dropdown menu.