# Perforce error - Path '/Users/aa/Documents' is not under client's root '/Users/aa/Documents/perforce/p4_project'

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v, perforce-integrate

I've come across many posts online, but it seems that this issue is a bit different or perhaps I'm unable to find another article that addresses the problem.

I'm encountering the error `Path '/Users/aa/Documents' is not under client's root '/Users/aa/Documents/perforce/p4_project'` when attempting to build a new project from terminal via p4 commands. The same commands work fine on my other machines like ubuntu or centos boxes. This error occurs only on my local Mac and I've followed these commands to create a new perforce project.

```
# pwd
=> /Users/aa/Documents/perforce
# mkdir p4_project
# cd p4_project
# echo "P4CLIENT=aa-p4_project" > .p4config
# p4 client -t MASTER-p4-project
=> trying to uncomment some directories and then try to do p4 sync
# p4 sync ...
=> Got this error - `Path '/Users/aa/Documents' is not under client's root '/Users/aa/Documents/perforce/p4_project' `
```

I've set the `P4CONFIG` variable and also ensured that I am in the same directory. See the `p4 info` output below

```
User name: aa
Client name: aa-p4_project
Client host: JYDL743YDFI
Client root: /Users/aa/Documents/perforce/p4_project    <<<----- same as current directory
Current directory: /Users/aa/Documents/perforce/p4_project
Peer address: 172.16.15.49:62849
Client address: 172.16.15.49
Server address: <server>:<port>
Server root: /p4/root
    :
    :
Case Handling: sensitive
```

Tried approaches mentioned on following pages (not similar issue though) :

- [p4 status "Path is not under client's root"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244976/p4-status-path-is-not-under-clients-root)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/oxr664/perforce_is_not_under_clients_root_folder_any/

Comment: Are you sure that nothing is happening in between the `p4 info` and `p4 sync` commands?  Did you run those in the same terminal window?  The error indicates that the current directory is a couple levels higher than the root.

Comment: Note that if you want to sync the whole client (which it seems like you do), no file arg is needed: `p4 sync` should do the trick regardless of the current directory, so long as P4CLIENT is correct.

Comment: @Samwise : Yes I tried to create project at least 5 times yesterday with these simple commands to rule out other possibilities. But no luck! I also tried to create a project at `/Users/aa/Documents` level but then it gives error like `Path '/Users/aa' is not under client's root '/Users/aa/Documents/p4_project'`.

Comment: Yes `p4 sync` works fine. Interesting, thanks! But I cannot run other p4 commands because of the same error.

Comment: Is it possible that something is happening with your shell where it's somehow turning `...` into `..`?  What if you specify an absolute path, like `p4 sync /Users/aa/Documents/perforce/...`?

Comment: It might help if you copied and pasted the exact terminal contents into the question -- the way that it's edited makes me wonder if there might be some clue (like a minor typo) that was lost in translation.  It's not clear what you mean by "uncomment some directories" and I'm wondering if whatever happened there is the source of the problem?

Comment: You're right @Samwise. I use zsh (z shell) and other plugins. ".." & "..." actually maps to "cd .." & "cd ../..". **It works if I specify full path.?** Thanks a lot Samwise. I appreciate it.

Comment: I've never heard of that.  O_o  If you can disable that plugin, I'd recommend it, since `...` gets used a lot in Perforce.  The behavior of `cd`ing as a side effect of providing `..` as an arg to another command also sounds like it could potentially be very confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Samwise answered my question in the comments. The issue was that ".." and "..." were mapped to "cd .." and "cd ../.." respectively. The **p4** command works correctly if I use an absolute path or escape the "."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).